# Loops that store different variables per iteration?

Tags: python, loops

Is there a way I can shorten this code to perhaps use a loop that stores different variables each time it is run? I need it to store different variables rather than overwriting the same variable in the loop. As of right now they code is very lengthy and ends after five iterations, as coded, before displaying my end results. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
while True:

opps = float(input("Number of opportunities: "))

sales = float(input("Quantity of of sales: "))

addon = float(input("Addon $ amount: "))

total = float(input("Sales dollar amount: "))

cra =  (sales / opps) * 100 

addonp = (addon / total) * 100

print("Results:\n" +
"CRA %: " + str(cra) + "%\n" +
"Addon %: " + str(addonp) + "%\n")

ans = 'y' 

ans = str(input("Continue? (Y/N)"))

if ans in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:

    opps2 = float(input("Number of opportunities: "))

    sales2 = float(input("Quantity of of sales: "))

    addon2 = float(input("Addon $ amount: "))

    total2 = float(input("Sales dollar amount: "))

    cra2 =  (sales2 / opps2) * 100 

    addonp2 = (addon2 / total2) * 100

    print("Results:\n" +
    "CRA %: " + str(cra2) + "%\n" +
    "Addon %: " + str(addonp2) + "%\n")

    ans = 'y' 

    ans = str(input("Continue? (Y/N)"))

if ans in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:

    opps3 = float(input("Number of opportunities: "))

    sales3 = float(input("Quantity of of sales: "))

    addon3 = float(input("Addon $ amount: "))

    total3 = float(input("Sales dollar amount: "))

    cra3 =  (sales3 / opps3) * 100 

    addonp3 = (addon3 / total3) * 100

    print("Results:\n" +
    "CRA %: " + str(cra3) + "%\n" +
    "Addon %: " + str(addonp3) + "%\n")

    ans = 'y' 

    ans = str(input("Continue? (Y/N)"))

if ans in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:

    opps4 = float(input("Number of opportunities: "))

    sales4 = float(input("Quantity of of sales: "))

    addon4 = float(input("Addon $ amount: "))

    total4 = float(input("Sales dollar amount: "))

    cra4 =  (sales4 / opps4) * 100 

    addonp4 = (addon4 / total4) * 100

    print("Results:\n" +
    "CRA %: " + str(cra4) + "%\n" +
    "Addon %: " + str(addonp4) + "%\n")

    ans = 'y' 

    ans = str(input("Continue? (Y/N)"))

if ans in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:

    opps5 = float(input("Number of opportunities: "))

    sales5 = float(input("Quantity of of sales: "))

    addon5 = float(input("Addon $ amount: "))

    total5 = float(input("Sales dollar amount: "))

    cra5 =  (sales5 / opps5) * 100 

    addonp5 = (addon5 / total5) * 100

    print("Results:\n" +
    "CRA %: " + str(cra5) + "%\n" +
    "Addon %: " + str(addonp5) + "%\n")

    ans = 'y' 

    ans = str(input("Continue? (Y/N)"))


if ans not in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:

    oppst = opps + opps2 + opps3 + opps4 + opps5

    salest = sales + sales2 + sales3 + sales4 + sales5

    addont = addon + addon2 + addon3 + addon4 + addon5

    cratp = (salest / oppst) * 100

    tsales = total + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5

    addontp = (addont / tsales) * 100

    int(oppst)
    int(salest)

    print("Your totals are: \n" + 
"\n" +
"Opportunities: " + str(int(oppst)) + "\n" +
"\n" +
"# of Sales: " + str(int(salest)) + "\n" +
"\n" +
"Addon $ amount: " + "$" + str(addont) + "\n" +
"\n" +
"Addon %: " + str(addontp) + "%\n" +
"\n" +
"CRA %: " +  str(cratp) + "%\n" +
"\n" +
"Total Sales: " + "$" + str(tsales)
        )
    break
```

Comment: Can you please repost correctly formatted code.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-HLU9Fl5ug should give you some ideas on how you could solve this.

Comment: You should learn about the concept of **lists** in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ans = 'y'
opps = []
sales = []
addon = []
while ans not in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:
    opps.append(float(input("Number of opportunities: ")))
    sales.append(float(input("Quantity of of sales: ")))
    addon.append(float(input("Addon $ amount: ")))
    total.append(float(input("Sales dollar amount: ")))

    cra =  (sales[-1] / opps[-1]) * 100
    addonp = (addon[-1] / total[-1]) * 100
    print("Results:\n" + "CRA %: " + str(cra) + "%\n" +"Addon %: " + str(addonp) + "%\n")

    ans = str(input("Continue? (Y/N)"))

oppst = sum(opps)
salest = sum(sales)
addont = sum(addon)
cratp = (salest / oppst) * 100
tsales = sum(sales)
addontp = (addont / tsales) * 100

print("Your totals are: \n" + "\n" + "Opportunities: " + str(int(oppst)) + "\n" + "\n" + "# of Sales: " + str(int(salest)) + "\n" + "\n" + "Addon $ amount: " + "$" + str(addont) + "\n" + "\n" + "Addon %: " + str(addontp) + "%\n" + "\n" + "CRA %: " +  str(cratp) + "%\n" + "\n" + "Total Sales: " + "$" + str(tsales))
```

**Explanation:**

Simply put, you want to use `lists`. They're used whenever you want to store multiple data values under one variable. In this case, there's no need to create new variables each time as you can simply append (add) to the list. The loop will run as long as `ans` is in the whitelist. When it ends, your code for calculating the totals will run (note that `sum()` can be used to calculate the sum of variables, or in this case, a list).

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for the format I didn’t notice that until after. I know the concept of lists but understanding is so much different from application. Thanks again!

Comment: small typo: in the while print `cra5` and `addonp5`

Comment: @bobrobbob Thanks! Edited :)